# HTML/JavaScript Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Please, can you help me with Drag and drop functions?
Needed behavior is, that:

- drag function will start after long-click (2000ms),
- and if I will move dragged div, the others will move out of its way (making space where I can drop it).
- It should be able to drop it on the same shelf, but also on the another one.
- When I press Esc while dragging, it will jump right back (it is working now)

I am using HTML5 native Drag and Drop but I have no idea how to enable it after long click and the Drop function is not working too.

Draggable div has `<div class="file" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">`

The "drop area" has `<div class="shelf" id="shelf1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">`

And the Drag and Drop JS is:

```
  function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
  function drag(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  }
  function drop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
```

Please, do you have any tips how to expand it for the needed behavior?

Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! By using jQueryUI library http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

```
// For Drag and Drop is used JS library jQuery UI
  $("#shelf1, #shelf2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    // Wait X ms before dragging will start
    delay: 100,
    classes: {
      "ui-sortable-helper": "draggable-chosen"
    }
  }).disableSelection();

  // When the Esc is pressed, return to original position
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 27 || e.keyCode === 27) {
      $("#shelf1, #shelf2").sortable("cancel");
    }
  });
});
```